# How to overlay and average xarray plot images?

Tags: python, plot, average, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm new to Python. I have 2 netCDF files which I have used xarray to extract the variables and plot them accordingly.

The code is as below:

```
import xarray as xr
#Open dataset 1
dset = xr.open_dataset("dataset.nc")
print(dset)


#Extract tss variable from dataset 1
tss = dset['tss']
print(tss)


#Visualise 
dset['tss'].plot(cmap = 'rainbow',vmax = 20.0)
```

[image: image1]

```
#Open dataset 2
dset2 = xr.open_dataset("datset2.nc")
print(dset2)

#Extract tss variable from dataset 2
tss_2 = dset2['tss']
print(tss_2)

#Visualise 
tss_2.plot(cmap ='rainbow', vmax = 20.0)
```

[image: image2]

My next step is to produce an average image from these 2 images. How to move forward from here?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. E.g.

```
tss_avg = (tss*tss_2)/2
```

But I think in your case there is a much smarter way to handle this because xarray provides a lot of helpful features.

You should load all of your data into one Dataset. (Please not the difference between `DataArray` and `Dataset` on the [xarray documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html))

This can be done with `open_datasets`

```
data = xr.open_datasets(['dataset.nc','dataset2.nc'])
```

Now you can calculate the [mean](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.mean.html) of the variable

```
mean_tss = data.tss.mean()
mean_tss.plot(cmap ='rainbow', vmax = 20.0)
```

I hope you have fun working with xarray ;)